# Auto Scaling Pod using Kafka Metrics via Prometheus

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus

We are trying to Autoscale the Pods using HorizontalPodScaler, we are trying to scale based on Prometheus, we have set up Prometheus instance but unable to write metrics to Prometheus using Kafka exporter, is there any clear approach for doing this?

Comment: Can you post specifically what you have tried and how it is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HPA using Kafka Exporter in on premise Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361180/hpa-using-kafka-exporter-in-on-premise-kubernetes-cluster)